# How does one add boarding passes to Apple Wallet?

Tags: ios, iphone, wallet

I have been trying to add some boarding passes to wallet. I have downloaded the airline app and logged in. I have tried to "scan the code" as suggested in wallet, but the only code is a QR code and nothing happens when I try to scan. This should be that difficult but I cannot figure it out. Is there an easy way to get this done? Please explain to me how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at the airline's policy on electronic boarding passes. My spouse booked flights for both of us on Southwest Airlines and neither one of us were able to get e-boarding passes in that case. There should be a help or info button in the app for that.

Comment: If you tell us which airline you booked the flights with we might be able to give you a specific answer. Each airline tends to do things differently.

Comment: United Airlines.

Comment: Hey, you can use this free tool:
https://getpassbook.com

It will convert any PDF boarding pass into iOS one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### If your airline is Delta

Check into your flight with [this page](https://www.delta.com/PCCOciWeb/findBy.action) of Delta's website on your iPhone/iPod Touch (have your flight's confirmation number ready). When you complete your checkin, you will be given an option to add the pass to your Passbook (aka Wallet app). Tap into that, then press the `Add` button to add the pass to your wallet. Then you can skip the check-in kiosk at the airport if you have your phone and the pass handy.

---

### Any other airline

Download the airline's app (yep, only Delta lets you use the mobile site to add a boarding pass to Wallet) and open it up. Here are some apps from the major carriers (though don't fret if your airline is not on this list, it's rather incomplete; just search for it in the app store):

- [United](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/united-airlines/id449945214?mt=8)
- [JetBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jetblue/id481370590?mt=8)
- [Alaska](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alaska-airlines/id356143077?mt=8)
- [American Airlines](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/american-airlines/id382698565?mt=8)
- [RyanAir](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ryanair-cheapest-fares/id504270602?mt=8)

Proceed into the app (have your confirmation number or loyalty account info ready) and choose the `Check in` option (location of this button varies between apps). Follow the instructions to check in, and at the end, you'll see a button to `Add to Passbook` or `Add to Apple Wallet`. Press that, then press the `Add` button in the Navbar and you'll be set.

Comment: Does NOT work for Ryan Air. At the end of check in, you have to PRINT a boarding pass like in ancient times. OR you can let Ryan Air print it for you, adding yet more misc fees that often add up more than the original cost of the airlines.

Comment: @user252471 Oh dear, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I have Delta, and had checked in on a computer.  I found that when I logged into the Delta app on my iphone, I was able to navigate to my trip and add the boarding pass to my wallet there.  Just one other option.  Delta used to let me add the boarding pass directly to my wallet when I pulled up the boarding pass notification.  Kind of annoying to have that functionality taken away...